# React life cycle methods won't fire, when calling React.Component<props,state>'s render() method

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've got a parent react component, which dynamically generates an array of custom child elements. The parent's lifecycle methods are getting fired properly. It's child elements life cycle methods won't get called. My question is: why?

Parent:

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component<IParentProps, IParentState> {
  public children: Array<IChild & React.Component> = new ArrayArray<IChild & React.Component>();

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.children.push(new Child({
      options: {}
    }));
    this.children.push(new Child({
      options: {}
    }));

    console.log('constructor(props)');
  }

  public componentWillMount() {
      // gets called
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IParentProps> {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.children[this.state.currentStep].render()}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Child:

```
export default class Child extends React.Component<IChildProps, IChildState> implements IChild {
  //#region IStep implementation
  //#endregion

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  public componentWillMount() {
      // won't get called, neither any other life cycle method, such as componentDidMount etc.
  }


  public render(): React.ReactElement<IChildProps> {
   // gets called
    return (
      <div>
        I am child
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: I never use the public keyword in my react classes, but I don't know if that is going to change anything here

Comment: It is implictly public, if you don't specify it. Therefore: it won't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not meant to ever call render directly.

You need to instead use Reacts mounting and management via [React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#creating-react-elements)

An example of how to achieve this:

```
render(): React.ReactElement<IParentProps> {
    return (
        <div>
            {React.createElement(this.children[this.state.currentStep], props, children)}
        </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Ah, I had a feeling that calling render() would be a 'bad' thing to do, but didn't know how the better (best) practice would be. It's a hard life as a backend dev in a frondend world. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't call render method of a child like this (/!\ bad practice).
React is unable to know that this component exist.
Here is a fix:

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component<IParentProps, IParentState> {
  public children: Array<IChild & React.Component> = new ArrayArray<IChild & React.Component>();

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.children.push(new Child({
      options: {}
    }));
    this.children.push(new Child({
      options: {}
    }));

    console.log('constructor(props)');
  }

  public componentWillMount() {
      // gets called
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IParentProps> {
    const Child = this.children[this.state.currentStep]
    return (
        <div>
            <Child />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, The comment in the Pandelis answer is also directed to you!